# Delayed_Jobs turns of sometimes and needs to be rest.. is that normal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Especially on a reboot and redeploy of the server, sometimes Delayed_Jobs does not turn back on even though it is explicitly booted via the recipes, and its running in a `ps aux | grep delayed` command.

Still the jobs won't be carried out unless I reboot it, even if no changes were made to the delayed_jobs themselves. That's how I know its not a caching issue.

It's gotten to the point, where I'm considering making a cron task that would reboot delayed_jobs every half hour just to ensure its up to par all the time. But I think this is way overkill.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would [recommend using god](http://god.rubyforge.org/) for that instead of a cron job, because it is fully ruby based it is great for writing config files totally in ruby. Obviously this won't actually solve your problem, but God really helped me out a lot rather than cron.

Comment: at first I thought you were an evangalist

Comment: haha yes I know, and sorry about that. The best part about using god is calling god.destroy, in my opinion. or start god